# Customizing ActionBlock<T>

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, tpl-dataflow

I want to implement a prioritised `ActionBlock<T>`. So that i can Conditionally give priority to some `TInput` items by using a `Predicate<T>`.
I read   [Parallel Extensions Extras Samples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx) and [Guide to Implementing Custom TPL Dataflow Blocks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/05/10244302.aspx).
But Still don`t figure out how can i implement this scenario.
---------------------------- EDIT ---------------------------
There are some tasks, which 5 of them can be run simultaneously. When user push the button, some (depends on predicate function) tasks should run with the most priority.
In fact i write this code

```
TaskScheduler taskSchedulerHighPriority;
ActionBlock<CustomObject> actionBlockLow;
ActionBlock<CustomObject> actionBlockHigh;
...
queuedTaskScheduler = new QueuedTaskScheduler(TaskScheduler.Default, 5);
taskSchedulerHigh = queuedTaskScheduler.ActivateNewQueue(0);
taskSchedulerLow = queuedTaskScheduler.ActivateNewQueue(1);
...
actionBlockHigh = new ActionBlock<CustomObject>(new Action<CustomObject>(method), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5, SingleProducerConstrained = false, TaskScheduler = taskSchedulerHigh });
actionBlockLow = new ActionBlock<CustomObject>(new Action<CustomObject>(method), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5, MaxMessagesPerTask = 1, TaskScheduler = taskSchedulerLow });
...     
if (predicate(customObject))
    actionBlockHigh.Post(customObject);
else
    actionBlockLow.Post(customObject);
```

But it seems priority does not take effected at all.
---------------------------- EDIT ------------------
I find the fact that when i use this line of code:

```
actionBlockHigh = new ActionBlock<AvlHistory>(new Action<AvlHistory>(SemaphoreAction), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { TaskScheduler = taskSchedulerHigh });
actionBlockLow = new ActionBlock<AvlHistory>(new Action<AvlHistory>(SemaphoreAction), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { TaskScheduler = taskSchedulerLow });
```

Cause application observe priorities of the Tasks correctly but only one task can be execute at a time, meanwhile using the first code block that is shown in flowing, cause application run 5 tasks simultaneously but in inappropriate priority order.

```
actionBlockHigh = new ActionBlock<AvlHistory>(new Action<AvlHistory>(SemaphoreAction), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5, TaskScheduler = taskSchedulerHigh });
actionBlockLow = new ActionBlock<AvlHistory>(new Action<AvlHistory>(SemaphoreAction), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5, TaskScheduler = taskSchedulerLow });
```

Update:
Tanks to svick, i should specify `MaxMessagesPerTask` for `taskSchedulerLow`.

Comment: What is dictating the priority?  Is it something not related to `T` at all?  Or is the priority an inherent/derived property of `T`?

Comment: You can create a custom buffer block that uses a ConcurrentPriorityQueue or you can create a custom asynchronous transfromation block. Both options are non-trivial. Also agree with @casperOne, what does priority mean in your case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question doesn't include many details, so the following is just a guess of what you might need.

I think the simplest way to do this is to have two `ActionBlock`s, running on different priorities on [`QueuedTaskScheduler` from ParallelExtensionsExtras](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx). You would link to the high-priority one using a predicate and then to the low-priority one. Also, to make sure high-priority `Task`s aren't waiting, set `MaxMessagesPerTask` of the low-priority block.

In code, it would look something like:

```
static ITargetBlock<T> CreatePrioritizedActionBlock<T>(
    Action<T> action, Predicate<T> isPrioritizedPredicate)
{
    var buffer = new BufferBlock<T>();

    var scheduler = new QueuedTaskScheduler(1);

    var highPriorityScheduler = scheduler.ActivateNewQueue(0);
    var lowPriorityScheduler = scheduler.ActivateNewQueue(1);

    var highPriorityBlock = new ActionBlock<T>(
        action, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            TaskScheduler = highPriorityScheduler
        });
    var lowPriorityBlock = new ActionBlock<T>(
        action, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            TaskScheduler = lowPriorityScheduler,
            MaxMessagesPerTask = 1
        });

    buffer.LinkTo(highPriorityBlock, isPrioritizedPredicate);
    buffer.LinkTo(lowPriorityBlock);

    return buffer;
}
```

This is just a sketch of what you could do, for example, `Completion` of the returned block doesn't behave correctly.

Comment: In your code, you don't specify `MaxMessagesPerTask` for your low priority block. Like I said, doing that is quite imporant.